# Changing AlamoFire Config

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

In a class my project is using have a var to store the alamofire manager:

```
var alamoManager: Manager!
```

A method is called repeatedly in the app to config this manager like so:

```
func configAlamoManager() {

   let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
   configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
   //ETC

   alamoManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
}
```

I have a HTTP call in my app that is ocasiaonally returning a `999 canceled` error code. I suspect this is because the manager currently trying to perform the request is replaced by another one from the  `configAlamoManager()` method. Is there any way to just change the config settings in the manager without creating a new instance? `alamoManager.session.configuration` has no setter. Any pointers on this would be really appreciated! Thanks

Comment: any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the configuration and creating a new `Manager`, you should override the configuration in the actual `NSURLRequest`.

```
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(url: url)
urlRequest.timeoutInterval = 20

Alamofire.request(urlRequest).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

For more info on what you can override using an `NSURLRequest`, I'd check out the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/).